# Plugin preventing media buttons from working

Tags: jquery

When I have this plugin active (code below) the media button in the editor does not allow me to insert images. Any idea what needs to be fixed?

```
<?php
/*
* Plugin Name: Guest authors
* Description: For guest authors
* Version: 1.0
*/

$postcontributor_metabox_post = array( 
    'id' => 'postcontributor',
    'title' => 'Post Contributor',
    'page' => 'post',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'default',
    'fields' => $postcontributor_fields = array(


                array(
                    'name'          => 'Name',
                    'desc'          => 'Author name',
                    'id'            => 'ecpt_name',
                    'class'         => 'ecpt_name',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'rich_editor'   => 0,           
                    'max'           => 0                                                    
                ),

                array(
                    'name'          => 'Email',
                    'desc'          => 'Contributor Gravatar email',
                    'id'            => 'ecpt_email',
                    'class'         => 'ecpt_email',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'rich_editor'   => 1,           
                    'max'           => 0                                                    
                ),

                array(
                    'name'          => 'Bio',
                    'desc'          => 'Author bio',
                    'id'            => 'ecpt_bio',
                    'class'         => 'ecpt_bio',
                    'type'          => 'textarea',
                    'rich_editor'   => 0,           
                    'max'           => 0                                                    
                ),

                array(
                    'name'          => 'Photo',
                    'desc'          => 'Upload photo for bio box',
                    'id'            => 'ecpt_photo',
                    'class'         => 'ecpt_photo',
                    'type'          => 'upload',
                    'rich_editor'   => 0,           
                    'max'           => 0                                                    
                ),
                                                )
);          

add_action('admin_menu', 'ecpt_add_postcontributor_meta_box');
function ecpt_add_postcontributor_meta_box() {

    global $postcontributor_metabox_post;           

    add_meta_box($postcontributor_metabox_post['id'], $postcontributor_metabox_post['title'], 'ecpt_show_postcontributor_box', 'post', 'normal', 'default', $postcontributor_metabox_post);
}

// function to show meta boxes
function ecpt_show_postcontributor_box()    {
    global $post;
    global $postcontributor_metabox_post;
    global $ecpt_prefix;

    // Use nonce for verification
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="ecpt_postcontributor_meta_box_nonce" value="', wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)), '" />';

    echo '<table class="form-table">';

    foreach ($postcontributor_metabox_post['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data

        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);

        echo '<tr>',
                '<th style="width:20%"><label for="', $field['id'], '">', $field['name'], '</label></th>',
                '<td>';
        switch ($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                echo '<input type="text" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" /><br/>', '', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'date':
                echo '<input type="text" class="ecpt_datepicker" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:97%" />', '', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'upload':
                echo '<input type="text" class="ecpt_upload_field" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" value="', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '" size="30" style="width:80%" /><input class="upload_image_button" type="button" value="Upload Image" /><br/>', '', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                if($field['rich_editor'] == 1) {
                    // this is the old method of enabling the RTE. Now it only needs the class name.
                    //wp_tiny_mce(true, array('editor_selector' => $field['class'], 'remove_linebreaks' => false) );
                    echo '<div style="width: 97%; border: 1px solid #DFDFDF;"><textarea name="', $field['id'], '" class="theEditor ', $field['class'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="8" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea></div>', '', $field['desc'];
                } else {
                    echo '<div style="width: 100%;"><textarea name="', $field['id'], '" class="', $field['class'], '" id="', $field['id'], '" cols="60" rows="8" style="width:97%">', $meta ? $meta : $field['std'], '</textarea></div>', '', $field['desc'];               
                }
                break;
            case 'select':
                echo '<select name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '">';
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $option . '"', $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '', '>', $option, '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>', '', $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {
                    echo '<input type="radio" name="', $field['id'], '" value="', $option, '"', $meta == $option ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' /> ', $option;
                }
                echo '<br/>' . $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                echo '<input type="checkbox" name="', $field['id'], '" id="', $field['id'], '"', $meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '', ' /> ';
                echo $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'slider':
                echo '<input type="text" rel="' . $field['max'] . '" name="' . $field['id'] . '" id="' . $field['id'] . '" value="' . $meta . '" size="1" style="float: left; margin-right: 5px" />';
                echo '<div class="ecpt-slider" rel="' . $field['id'] . '" style="float: left; width: 60%; margin: 5px 0 0 0;"></div>';      
                echo '<div style="width: 100%; clear: both;">' . $field['desc'] . '</div>';
                break;
        }
        echo     '<td>',
            '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
}   

add_action('save_post', 'ecpt_postcontributor_save');

// Save data from meta box
function ecpt_postcontributor_save($post_id) {
    global $post;
    global $postcontributor_metabox_post;

    // verify nonce
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['ecpt_postcontributor_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach ($postcontributor_metabox_post['fields'] as $field) {
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ($new && $new != $old) {
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
        }
    }
}


function ecpt_export_ui_scripts() {

    global $ecpt_options;
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {

            if(jQuery('.form-table .ecpt_upload_field').length > 0 ) {
                // Media Uploader
                window.formfield = '';

                jQuery('.upload_image_button').live('click', function() {
                window.formfield = jQuery('.ecpt_upload_field',jQuery(this).parent());
                    tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=file&TB_iframe=true');
                                    return false;
                    });

                    window.original_send_to_editor = window.send_to_editor;
                    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
                        if (window.formfield) {
                            imgurl = jQuery('a','<div>'+html+'</div>').attr('href');
                            window.formfield.val(imgurl);
                            tb_remove();
                        }
                        else {
                            window.original_send_to_editor(html);
                        }
                        window.formfield = '';
                        window.imagefield = false;
                    }
            }
            if(jQuery('.form-table .ecpt-slider').length > 0 ) {
                jQuery('.ecpt-slider').each(function(){
                    var $this = jQuery(this);
                    var id = $this.attr('rel');
                    var val = jQuery('#' + id).val();
                    var max = jQuery('#' + id).attr('rel');
                    max = parseInt(max);
                    //var step = $('#' + id).closest('input').attr('rel');
                    $this.slider({
                        value: val,
                        max: max,
                        step: 1,
                        slide: function(event, ui) {
                            jQuery('#' + id).val(ui.value);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }

            if(jQuery('.form-table .ecpt_datepicker').length > 0 ) {
                var dateFormat = 'mm-dd-yy';
                jQuery('.ecpt_datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat: dateFormat});
            }
        });
  </script>
<?php
}

function ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_scripts() {
    global $ecpt_base_dir;
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui.min', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js', false, '1.8', 'all');
}
function ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_styles() {
    global $ecpt_base_dir;
    wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-css', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css', false, '1.8', 'all');
}

// these are for newest versions of WP
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_scripts-edit.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_scripts-post-new.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_scripts');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_styles');
add_action('admin_print_styles-edit.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_styles');
add_action('admin_print_styles-post-new.php', 'ecpt_export_datepicker_ui_styles');

if ((isset($_GET['post']) && (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == 'edit') ) || (strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-admin/post-new.php')))
{
    add_action('admin_head', 'ecpt_export_ui_scripts');
}
```

Comment: Can you narrow this down? Comment out bits of code until you see functionality return, then update the question. My bet is on the Javascript, by the way.

Comment: Yes it is the JS which is causing this, of course if I remove it things work but it is important for the scope of the plugin.